# If decryption key is hacked then is it safe to change encryption and decryption key?

Tags: cryptography

Suppose the decryption key $d$ of a RSA cryptosystem is hacked and instead of choosing a new $n$ if encryption and decryption keys are changed with same $n$,then is this safe ?

My attempt: Previous encryption key $e$ and decryption key $d$ are known.
Then $ed \equiv 1$(mod $\varphi(n)$)

i.e, $\;ed-1 = k \cdot \varphi(n)$, for some natural number $k$.

$\implies \varphi(n) =\frac{ed-1}{k}$

So we get $\varphi(n)$ and could get prime factors of n.

Is this right?

Comment: But you need to get $k$ and $\varphi(n)$ to make this work.  How do you do that?  In other words, you can't get $\varphi(n)$ without knowing $k$, and you can't get $k$ without knowing $\varphi(n)$.  And clearly, if you know $\varphi(n)$ you know everything.

Comment: Also, if you get $\varphi(n)$, you don't need to factor $n$ anymore.

Comment: Anyway, you can consider what happens when the same plaintext is encrypted under the two distinct keys (same $n$).  There is a vulnerability there.

Comment: Yes, if the new and old encryption keys are coprime then finding integers $u,v$ such that $e_1u+e_2v=1$ ,ciphertext can be decrypted.

Comment: But if they are not coprime then is there any vulnerability?

Comment: The probability that they are coprime is VERY high.

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability as mentioned by @Randall, here is additional detail.

From [the paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-78440-1_3.pdf), "Solving Systems of Modular Equations in One
Variable: How Many RSA-Encrypted Messages
Does Eve Need to Know?" by Alexander May and Maike Ritzenhofen:

> G. Simmons [16] has presented a neat attack for this special setting
> with running time polynomial in the bitlength of $(e_1, e_2)$. Namely,
> one computes integers $u_1, u_2$ such that $u_1e_1+u_2e_2 = 1$ with
> the help of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. This gives us $m = (m^{e_1})^{u_1} (m^{e_2})^{u_2} \pmod{N}$.

...

> References
>
> [16]: Simmons, G.: A “Weak” Privacy Protocol Using the RSA Crypto Algorithm. Cryptologia 7(2), 180–182 (1983)

The original [Simmons paper is here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0161-118391857900).